# NullReferenceException when building Xamarin Android Binding Library

Tags: xamarin

I've been trying to build a Xamarin Android Binding Library having a .jar file in it.
It builds just as expected with different .jar-s I tried, however when I add jackson-databind library, I keep receiving

> BINDINGSGENERATOR : error BG0000: System.NullReferenceException:
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Bindings.Core.targets(53,5):
> message BG0000: error BG0000: System.NullReferenceException: Object
> reference not set to an instance of an object.

[image]

I have tried changing between Java 8 and Java 17, changing between Android SDK version. Nothing helps.

the build log does not give any hint on what object is being attempted to be accessed.

Moreover, when I use the same library in Android Studio, it builds and runs with no issue.

The log is too long so I pasted it here:

https://pastebin.pl/view/5b75b9ff
Any ideas what to look at next?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please post the steps so that we can try to reproduce this on our side?

Comment: Steps to reproduce:
1) Create Android Bindings Library (Xamarin) project
2) In the Jars folder, add the newest version of Jackson Databind library (download .jar file here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind)
3) Change .jar file Build Action to EmbeddedJar
4) Rebuild the solution
Now you will see the Null Ref. Exception.
In the mean time, I was able to hide the exception by removing the jackson-binding package alltogether in the metadata.xml:
  <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.fasterxml.jackson.databind']" /> This brought new errors.

Comment: `This brought new errors.` Could you please post the full error log about this error?